# Testroid code differs from Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I recorded and testroid generated Robotium code for me :

```
public void testRecorded() throws Exception {
        try {
            solo.waitForActivity("SplashScreen");
            solo.waitForActivity("TutorialActivity");
            solo.sleep(3100);
            solo.drag(solo.toScreenX(0.988f), solo.toScreenX(0.134f),
                solo.toScreenY(0.523f), solo.toScreenY(0.581f), 6);
```

But when i pasted the same code in my Robotium code which i manually wrote so, It is not recognising the solo.toScreen, solo.clickOnView(solo.findViewById

It gives error as cant resolve ..

Is there some inbuild class for testroid that are not in Robotium.

Comment: Please request some one to reply asap

Answer (score 0):

Testdroid Recorder uses extra library, which has class ExtSolo. This class extends Solo and provides extra methods. Api and library can be found here:
http://docs.testdroid.com/_pages/extsolo.html